# Drawing to a texture in Unity is very slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been learning Unity for the last few weeks in order to create a simple ant simulation. The way I was rendering everything was writing to a texture the size of the camera in the `Update` function. It works, but problem is that it is extremely slow, getting only around 3-4 FPS doing so. What could be done to speed it up? Maybe a completely different way of rendering?

Here is the code of a simple test where some Ants just move around in random directions. I have the `AntScript.cs` attached to the camera with a texture under a `Canvas` where everything is being written to.

`AntScript.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class Ant 
{
    public int thisX, thisY, val;
    public bool carryingFood = false;
    
    public Ant(int x, int y) 
    {
        thisX = x;
        thisY = y;
    }
}

public class AntScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Texture2D myTexture;
    public int imageWidth = 1920;
    public int imageHeight = 1080;
    public int gridWidth = 160;
    public int gridHeight = 90;
    private int cellSize;
    public GameObject imageElement;

    private List<Ant> ants = new List<Ant>();

    void Start() 
    {
        // Initialise texture

        myTexture = new Texture2D(
            imageWidth, 
            imageHeight, 
            TextureFormat.ARGB32, 
            false
        );
        
        // Calculate the size of a grid pixel
        cellSize = (int)Math.Min(
            imageWidth / gridWidth, 
            imageHeight / gridHeight
        );
        Debug.Log(cellSize);
 
        // Add test ants
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
            {
                ants.Add(new Ant(i * 4, j * 4));
            }
        }
    }

    void updImage() 
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        List<int> xDirs = new List<int> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1};
        List<int> yDirs = new List<int> {1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1};

/*--------------------- UPDATE ALL ELEMENTS ---------------------*/

        // Move ants
        foreach (Ant ant in ants) 
        {
            int randDirInt = rnd.Next(0, 8);
            ant.thisX += xDirs[randDirInt];
            ant.thisY += yDirs[randDirInt];
        }

/*--------------------- DRAW ALL ELEMENTS ---------------------*/

        // Clear texture
        for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) 
            {
                myTexture.SetPixel(i, j, Color.black);
            }
        }
        
        // Draw ants
        foreach (Ant ant in ants) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cellSize; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cellSize; j++) 
                {
                    myTexture.SetPixel(
                        ant.thisX * cellSize + i, 
                        ant.thisY * cellSize + j, 
                        Color.white
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        myTexture.Apply();

        imageElement.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(
            myTexture, 
            new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
        );
    }
    
    void Update() 
    {
        updImage();
    }
}
```

Elements in scene:

[image: elements]

Script arguments:

[image: script args]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general instead of using [`Texture2D.SetPixel`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) on individual pixels rather use [`Texture2D.GetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) and [`Texture2D.SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) on the entire image (or the section you changed).

This is already way more efficient!

Then using [`Texture2D.GetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html) and [`Texture2D.SetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html) which do use raw byte color format (0 to 255 instead of 0f to 1f) is even faster!

```
var pixels = myTexture.GetPixels32();
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++) 
{
    pixels[i] = Color.black;
}
    
    // Draw ants
foreach (Ant ant in ants)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cellSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellSize; j++) 
        {
            // TODO: calculate the index of the pixel in the flat array
            // Not 100% sure on that one tbh ;)
            var index = (ant.thisX * cellSize + i) + myTexture.width * (ant.thisY * cellSize + j);
            
            pixels[index] = Color.white
        }
    }
}

myTexture.SetPixels32(pixels);

myTexture.Apply();
```

In general though doing such pixel based stuff is always going to be quite expensive - so you could e.g. shift the heavy work into a thread/task and only update once it is done or use some native plugin to directly manipulate the underlying textures.

Then to make it even faster, do not clear the entire image all the time. It should be enough to just take the current ant positions, clear these pixels, then move the ants, then write the new pixels.

```
var pixels = myTexture.GetPixels32();

foreach (Ant ant in ants)
{
    var gridX = ant.thisX * cellSize;
    var gridY = ant.thisY * cellSize;

    // Clear current pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < cellSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellSize; j++) 
        {
            // TODO: calculate the index of the pixel in the flat array
            // Not 100% sure on that one tbh ;)
            var index = (gridX + i) + myTexture.width * (gridY + j);
            
            pixels[index] = Color.black;
        }
    }

    // move this ant
    int randDirInt = rnd.Next(0, 8);
    ant.thisX += xDirs[randDirInt];
    ant.thisY += yDirs[randDirInt];

    gridX = ant.thisX * cellSize;
    gridY = ant.thisY * cellSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < cellSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellSize; j++) 
        {
            // TODO: calculate the index of the pixel in the flat array
            // Not 100% sure on that one tbh ;)
            var index = (gridX + i) + myTexture.width * (gridY + j);
            
            pixels[index] = Color.white
        }
    }
}

myTexture.SetPixels32(pixels);

myTexture.Apply();
```

and only the first time initialize

```
private void Start()
{
    ...

    // Clear texture
    var pixels = myTexture.GetPixels();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) 
        {
            pixels[i * imageWidth + j] = Color.black;
        }
    }
    myTexture.SetPixels(pixels);
}
```

---

Also note that the

```
imageElement.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(
        myTexture, 
        new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 
        new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
    );
```

is absolutely unnecessary! Just stick to one `Sprite` instance. Whenever you change the texture's pixels afterwards any `Sprite` referencing this texture will display the same changes anyway.

Just assign and create that sprite **ONCE** and then don't care about it anymore.

```
void Start() 
{
    // Initialise texture

    myTexture = new Texture2D(
        imageWidth, 
        imageHeight, 
        TextureFormat.ARGB32, 
        false
    );

    imageElement.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(
        myTexture, 
        new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 
        new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
    );

    ...
}
```

---

And yet another point for improvement: Make these readonly and don't create and then forget them over and over again. This just causes a lot of work for the GC

```
private readonly System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
private readonly List<int> xDirs = new List<int> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1};
private readonly List<int> yDirs = new List<int> {1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1};

void updImage() 
{
    // Move ants
    foreach (Ant ant in ants) 
    {
        var randDirInt = rnd.Next(0, 8);
        ant.thisX += xDirs[randDirInt];
        ant.thisY += yDirs[randDirInt];
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think I understood how it works, thanks. However, it starts spitting out errors that the index is out of bounds, so I'm trying to fix that now. `pixels` a one-dimensional array, right?

Comment: yes it is one dimensional ... tbh I didn't really understand how exactly you calculated the positions so far (`ant.thisX * cellSize + i`) and `ant.thisY * cellSize + j` so weren't quite sure what the correct index should be ... but in general if you have a 2D array (i,j) you would go like `i + j * width` to convert it to a flat access, that's what I tried to do

Comment: I'll try to debug this further. If it's one-dimensional, does it just contain rows in order?

Comment: @Dion yes afaik it is layed out like `0,0 - 1,0 - 2,0 - ... n,0 - 0,1 - 1,1 - 2,1 - ... n,1` etc so row by row starting bottom left

Comment: Well this is a bit weird, it's reporting that `pixels.Length` is equal to 12... Only 12 pixels? :D

Comment: @Dion indeed 12 sounds pretty low :D See [`Texture2D.GetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) this shouldn't be the case ^^ one would expect `1920 * 1080` according to your settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233779/discussion-between-dion-and-derhugo).

Answer (score 0):

Does the image need to be updated every frame or perhaps 3-5 times/second?
void Update updates every single frame, the calculations you are causing unity to do exceed what is expected of the update function. Basically, 1 second divided by calculation time = FPS. If there is time between the ants movement (other logic needing to happen before an update) I would recommend sliding your updImage(); into a condition to limit its calls in the update function, such as:

```
var i = 0;
    void Update() {
          if (i >= 12){
          updImage();
          i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

This will limit its call to once ever 12 frames, however, as you've mentioned you're currently only getting 3-4 fps, which means that in order for this to be effective we would need to limit the calls to once every 30 frames. This will decrease the load on Unity and free up fps for other calculations, however that being said, the ant update animation set to 30 "if (i >= 30)" the ant updates would only occur twice every second at a target framerate of 60fps.

Now, personally, I would be using individual sprites with the instantiate and destroy functions instead of changing pixels in an image, and updating their locations via coordinates in unity's 2d space instead of replacing the image every frame. This alone would take a load off of the editor.

Another option is to change void Update to void FixedUpdate

```
var i = 0;
    void FixedUpdate() {
          if (i >= 25){
          updImage();
          i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

[fixed update is set to 50 updates/s by default](https://john-tucker.medium.com/unity-update-versus-fixedupdate-7a4d4d7bc1f5) this is typically used for updating physics or other movements that require a steady timestep rather than depending on fps to get the job done.
A link to the instantiate and destroy docs here- [instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), [destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up your code 1000 times faster, then replace

```
imageElement.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(
        myTexture, 
        new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 
        new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
    );
```

with this:

```
imageElement.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = 
  Sprite.Create(
    myTexture, 
    new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 
    new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 
    pixelsPerUnit: 100, 
    extrude: 0, 
    SpriteMeshType.FullRect);
```

The magic done by the last parameter. If you don't specify SpriteMeshType.FullRect, then the default will be SpriteMeshType.Tight and that tries to build some custom outline, which is slow.

Have a nice day,

FunRobGames